# Wait for 50 years to unlock

Tags: iphone, password, ios, unlock

Today I wanted to backup my old iPhone which I didn't use for a long time and never tried to unlock it for one year now. It was just laying around. Upon charging and starting it up, I saw this message:

`"IPhone is deactivated. In 24.286.924 minutes you can try again"`

Why this could possibly happen and what can I do about it?

[image: Thats the screen]

Comment: The date and time is wrong in the phone. If it can connect to internet it will set the clock itself. Try connecting it to iTunes and see what iTunes think about that.

Comment: See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204306.

Answer (score 2):

Date/time was wrong on the iPhone. I bought a new sim, it connected to the internet (and then adjusted date/time automatically) and that did the trick.